# Wpf grouped combobox with an expander

Tags: wpf

I was able to find an example of a grouped combobox here http://www.jarloo.com/wpf-combobox-with-groupings/

Its perfect for my use except I need an additional behavior. The items should all be collapsible under their respective headers (Using expanders).

For eg.
Fruit
 Apple
 Orange
 Grape
Animals
 Cat
 Dog
 Cow

The above items will be displayed in a combobox in a grouped style but I will like each headers (Here it would be Fruit, Animals) to be collapsible using an expander. Could you please help with an example?

Thanks,
Chev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GroupItem" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2,5,0,2" FontSize="14"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <Expander.Content>
                            <Border Margin="5,0,0,0">
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </Expander.Content>
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
<ComboBox Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="162,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="195" DisplayMemberPath="Item" Name="cboGroup">
    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupItem}"/>
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
</ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a `ComboBox`. The WPF `TreeView` natively supports this behavior. Example from MSDN below.

[image]

**Note**: This doesn't have the dropdown functionality you were looking for.

Your code would look like this:

```
<TreeView SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
  <TreeViewItem Header="Fruit">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Apple"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Orange"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Grape"/>
  </TreeViewItem>
 <TreeViewItem Header="Animals">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Cat"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Dog"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Cow"/>
  </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

**Edit:** Added additional code to prevent the user from clicking on the header items, and instead it just collapses/expands the node.

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    var item = e.NewValue as TreeViewItem;
    if (item == null ||item.Items.Count == 0) return;
    item.IsExpanded = !item.IsExpanded;
    item.IsSelected = false;
}
```

**Edit:** And here id a preview of what that would look like

[image]

Comment: Using a treeivew means the expandable items thats the parent is selectable. Whereas using grouping, the group header itself isn't selectable. Having a selectable parent may confuse the user into thinking that a valid item to pick.

Comment: @JoelLucsy That is a valid point so I have now edited my sample to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Still seems like a hack. Not very usable in a MVVM system. Group styling is really the way to go.

Comment: @JoelLucsy While this could indeed be done with some not so fun styles, triggers, bindings, converters... I did not take that route... I think I would have had to create a custom converter, which while easy to do... is more code than the above implementation.... but would be usable in MVVM... short story.. lazy